# $X_n$ have unif. dist. $(0,1)$, $|p| < 1$. $Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_1^p}{X_2^p} + (...) + \frac{X_{n-1}^p}{X_{n}^p} \right) $ is conv. a. s.

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, uniform-distribution

I've been working with exercises on convergence of series of random variables and found such a problem.

$X_1, X_2, X_3, (...), X_n$ are independent random variables with uniform distribution on $(0,1)$. Show that for $|p| < 1$ a series of random variables defined as:

$$Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_1^p}{X_2^p} + \frac{X_2^p}{X_3^p} + (...) + \frac{X_n^p}{X_{n+1}^p}  \right) $$

Is convergent almost surely and find $ \displaystyle x = \lim_{n \to \infty} Y_n $.

---

I will use the Kolmogorov's strong law of large numbers for series of variables with same distribution.

For that, variables $X$ in such a way to form other variables that would be independent. I have that:

$$Y_n = \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_1^p}{X_2^p} + \frac{X_2^p}{X_3^p} + (...) + \frac{X_n^p}{X_{n+1}^p}  \right) = $$
$$ =\frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_1^p}{X_2^p} + \frac{X_3^p}{X_4^p} + (...)  \right) + \left( \frac{X_2^p}{X_3^p} + \frac{X_4^p}{X_5^p} + (...) \right)$$

Additionally, I know that, for independent random variables $A$, $B$: $\mathbb{E}(AB) = \mathbb{E}(A) \mathbb{E}(B)$. Therefore:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}(|Y_n|) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \Big| \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_1^p}{X_2^p} + \frac{X_2^p}{X_3^p} + (...) + \frac{X_n^p}{X_{n+1}^p}  \right) \Big| \right) = $$

$E$ is linear and all $X_n$ have positive values, so we get:

$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_1^p}{X_2^p} + \frac{X_3^p}{X_4^p} + (...)  \right) \right) + \mathbb{E} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{X_2^p}{X_3^p} + \frac{X_4^p}{X_5^p} + (...) \right) \right) =$$

For independent random variables $A$, $B$ : $ \ \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( \frac{A}{B} \right)^p \right] = \mathbb{E}[(A)^p] \cdot \mathbb{E}[(B)^{-p}]$, therefore:

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \mathbb{E} (X_1^p) \cdot \mathbb{E} (X_2^{-p}) + (...)  \right) \right) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \mathbb{E} (X_2^p) \cdot \mathbb{E} (X_3^{-p}) + (...) \right) \right) = $$

From the law of the unconscious statistician, we have that for $|p| < 1$ and $i \in [1, n]$:

- $\mathbb{E} (X_i^p) = \int_0^1 x_i^p \ dx = \frac{1}{p+1}$
- $\mathbb{E} (X_i^{-p}) = \int_0^1 x_i^{-p} \ dx = \frac{1}{-p+1}$

(because our PDF for uniform distribution is equal to $1$).

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{p+1} \cdot \frac{1}{-p+1} + (...)  \right) \right) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{p+1} \cdot \frac{1}{-p+1} + (...) \right) \right) =$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{1-p^2} + (...)  \right) \right) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{1}{1-p^2} + (...) \right) \right) =$$

In each of $2$ parts we have $\frac{n}{2}$ elements, therefore:

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-p^2} \right) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{n}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-p^2} \right) =$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{2(1-p^2)} \right) + \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{1}{2(1-p^2)} \right) =$$
$$= \frac{1}{2(1-p^2)} + \frac{1}{2(1-p^2)} =$$
$$= \frac{2}{2(1-p^2)} =$$
$$= \frac{1}{1-p^2}$$

From that we see that $x = \frac{1}{1-p^2}$.

Comment: Hint: Look at the sum of every other term.

Comment: Thenk you for your input! I know they are independent then. I can make one series into 2 as you mentioned. The problem is that I don't think I can tell much about independent variables of form $\left( \frac{X_1}{X_2} \right)^p$ where both $X_1$ and $X_2$ are of uniform distribution. Those just don't mix together that well I guess. @kimchilover

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician for the last bit you are missing

Comment: @FZan thank you! I think I get it now. So I vave to use LOTUS and then that if X and Y are independent: $E(XY) = E(X)E(Y)$ and then think in terms of convergence in mean. Is that correct?

Comment: I edited my question. Is it any good? @kimchilover

Comment: I edited my question with an answer, Do you think it's correct? @FZan

Comment: You want $E[(X/Y)^p]$, which is $E[X^p] EY^{-p}]$. It is not the case that $E[X^p] = (E[X])^p$.  But you surely know the correct calculus formula you need to use.

Comment: @kimchilover No, unfortunately I guess I don't know.

Comment: @mathman12 If $X$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, then it's precisely the law of the unconscious statistician that allows you to write $\mathbb{E}[X^p] = \int_0^1 x^p\, {\rm d}x$ [without first finding the distribution of $X^p$].

Comment: You want to evaluate the integrals $\int_0^1 x^p\,dx$ and $\int_0^1x^{-p}\,dx$, paying attention to which values of $p$ make the integrals finite.

Comment: Ohhh, I' stupid. You are right, I didn't know where to use the law od unconscious statistician. I am sorry. I will edit my question now. This time it might be right. Thank you!

Comment: You're still making about the same overarching mistake.  The expected value of the quotient $\mathbb{E}[X/Y]$, for independent $X,Y$, is **almost never** the quotient of the expectations $\mathbb{E}[X]/\mathbb{E}[Y]$.  Instead, you need to follow one of the above comments' advice and write $\mathbb{E}[X/Y] = \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y^{-1}]$

Comment: @BrianMoehring done. I don't understand the connection that I need to do with convergence a. s. How from that constant limit, that I got for convergence in probability do I go to convergence a. s.?

Comment: @BrianMoehring yeah, I see, near $p$. Ok. So that's the way of thinking: we calculate $L1$ (mean) convergence the limit. Then we know that if we have that limit, then the sequence has subsequence that converges to the same limit. Therefore we know that if there is convergence a. s., the limit must be the same as in $L1$. So it's enough to chceck for convergence a. s. using strong law of large numbers - right?

Comment: Please post the text of the strong law of large numbers you have access to.  There is of course a weaker version that assumes the variables have a finite second moment, but there's also a _stronger_ strong law of large numbers that only assumes the random variables have a finite _first_ moment.  The former doesn't apply, but the latter does, and it might explain an awful lot about why we're having so much trouble if you explain which version you're using.

Comment: I was thinking about the Kolmogorov's strong law. Could you show me the one operating on expected values only? @BrianMoehring

Comment: That doesn't tell me enough.  See, if you want, the pdf [here](https://www.math.hkust.edu.hk/~makchen/MATH5411/Chap1Sec7.pdf).  It does have one form labeled "Kolmogorov's criterion" which might be what you are talking about, but it also has "Kolmogorov's strong law of large numbers" which is what I was talking about as the "stronger" form.  (If you want another published text with the stronger form, see, e.g., Durrett's _Probability Theory and Examples_.  I think I have an old edition, but in 4th ed, it is on page 81)

Comment: Ok @BrianMoehring, I get it now. We can use the 'stronger' strong low because the distribution of all the random variables is equal. If it was parametrized and dependent on the index of random variable we would need to check the convergence of variance. I will correct the problem in a minute. Thank you.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I am editing the post. Sorry it took that long. Meanwhile I've got a question - that might be stupid, but I want to make sure. If we have one of $4$ convergences (in in distribution, in probability, in mean, almost surely) then we have that the sequence $S_n$ converges to some random variable $X$. Is that true that for every other convergence (one of $3$), it must converge to THE SAME X or not converge at all? I mean: in all convergences the limit must be equal (if they work), right?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I think it's correct now.